# Glob array by number value

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, glob

I'm using glob to array my sub directories

```
<?php
$items = glob("../albums/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo "$item\n ";
}
?>
```

he orders them by the alphabet, i'd like to order them by numbers

if i got sub-directories named 1 , 3 , 5 , 10

the will be arranged like this : 10, 1, 3, 5

i want them to be like this 1, 3, 5, 10

is there an option? thanks

**EDIT:**
now i found natsort($files);
and when im using it with:

```
$items = array_slice(glob('albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR), 0, 4);
natsort($items);
```

and my folders are 995-1000
it gives me this array : 995, 996, 997, 1000

Comment: did you try sort() http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I don't know what this will give, but have you tried GLOB_NOSORT ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [natsort()](http://php.net/natsort)

Comment: but now its making a conflict, when used in `$items = array_slice(glob('albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR), 0, 4);
natsort($items); ` and the folders are 995,996,997,998,999,1000 it gives the 995,996,997 and 1000

Comment: you need to do the sorting before the slicing: `$items = glob(..); natsort($items); $items = array_slice($items, 0, 4);`

Answer (score 6):

use `natsort` to sort the array in natural order:

```
natsort($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array after the glob:

```
sort($items, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using array sorting `natsort()` like this;

```
$items = glob("../albums/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
natsort($items);
```

Now if print this array then you get the proper result by this.

```
print_r($items);
```